# /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle (LoadError)

Tags: ruby

After installing ruby-rails-4.0 (4.0.2+dfsg-2) attempting to generate a new web application fails with the following error:

$ rails new hello
           ....
         run bundle install
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle (LoadError)

Comment: Sounds like you didn't install ruby, just rails. See my answer below for most up to date ruby/rails install.

Answer (score 3):

This will fix the issue:

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

You'll most likely run into other gem dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'
```

come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try with required packages

```
sudo gem install bundler
sudo apt-get install bison libffi-dev libgdbm-dev libyaml-dev sqlite3 libgmp-dev libssl-dev
```

if it is not exists in package manager try with `sudo gem install`

Answer (score 0):

How did you install, using apt-get? You may have better luck if you purge all of ruby and rails and install using rvm. This will also get you a newer version of Ruby I believe.  Anyways, first add the key.

```
 gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
```

Then install  RVM stable with ruby and rails

```
 \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

It will take a little bit of time to download, configure and install, but after you should have latest Ruby, with rails working.

You can check version with

```
 rvm -v
```

You can check ruby version with

```
 ruby -v
```

And you can check rails with

```
 rails - v
```

I just set this up myself and it installed Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.2.0

For more info see:
https://rvm.io/rvm/install